# Save all personal email address of my chat user

Tags: gmail

I am using gmail. I want save all my chat user personal email address in gmail contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cant save personal email address because gamil creating new id

eg. 09uuqlpep830m0dgun89wrhmcw@public.talk.google.co